# FTPS AUTH TLS - Do I need to re-authenticate after PASV?

Tags: c#, authentication, encryption, ftp, tls1.2

Building a small FTPS client (using TcpClient) to better understand how FTP works (mostly a learning experience).

So far I can connect on the control channel (port 21), issue AUTH TLS, grab the SslStream of the TcpClient connected on port 21, issue User/Pass commands and authenticate successfully over the SslStream.

Now, when I pass the FTP server PASV, I open a new TcpClient with that connection, no problem.  My question(s) is(are) this(these): How do I get an SslStream for that new connection?  Do I need to re-authenticate that SslStream?

Right now my code just hangs on AuthenticateAsClient:

```
var sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpDataClient.GetStream(), true, OnCertificateValidation, null);
try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_ftpServer, null, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

The same code on my control TcpClient works fine:

```
var sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpControlClient.GetStream(), true, OnCertificateValidation, null);
try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(_ftpServer, null, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

Now, the control TcpClient runs right after an AUTH TLS command is sent to the server.  I've tried sending AUTH TLS on the data channel with no luck.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

*edit*

A quick comment - if I use the straight GetStream from _tcpDataClient, I get a 250 response on the Control channel.  This leads me to think my Data channel isn't encrypted?  Is that correct?

Comment: The data channel is just a plain TCP (or TLS in case of FTPS) connection. Only the data are transferred in this connection, no authentication or similar. See [RFC959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) for how basic FTP works and FTPS and not different in the concepts.

Comment: Steffen, I see - my intention is to protect the data channel - looks like I need to send PBSZ <size of buffer> and PROT P to protect the data channel.  Ha, that worked! Now I need to figure out how to write via the SslStream.  Doing stream.Write(buffer) seems to work, but the response is hanging - which makes me think that the write isn't completing correctly.  I'll have to read up on what the write should look like.  Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference - Gotta end the write with a \r\n to let the server know "yeah, I'm done talking now." :)